# How do I receive interactions via outgoing webhook?

Tags: python, flask, discord, discord-interactions

I'm trying to make my Discord bot receive an interaction via outgoing webhook. It says in the docs that my endpoint needs to be ready to ACK a PING message, and that my endpoint must be set up to handle signature headers. I've completed both of these steps, but it won't work:
Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from discord_interactions import verify_key_decorator


bot = Flask(__name__)


@bot.route('/interactions', methods=['POST'])
@verify_key_decorator('437d74d7164783b1b7b2cb0db422daa216e5d03fb2ed1ff970c8caaea688f264') # noqa
def interactions():
    if request.json['type'] == 1:
        return jsonify({
            "type": 1
        })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run()
```

When I run the bot, there is no error message, but when I try to save the endpoint url, it won't save. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You also needs to set up the security and authorization as described in [Discord Developer Portal — Documentation — Receiving and Responding](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding#security-and-authorization)

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't work. I tried using the sample code they gave, and the discord-interactions module.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please include in your answer the most relevant parts of the linked page. The goal is for the answer to be complete on its own, without needing to visit the link